# memory allocation limit for a 32-bit app on a 64-bit system

Tags: windows, memory-management, malloc

Is the max limitation for malloc (virtual heap I guess?) for a 32-bit app on a 64-bit system (Windows 2003 SP2 x64, to be specific) 2GB?

I'm basically trying to push a program beyond that with no luck. So I was wondering if that holds true for ALL 32-bit apps on Win x64 bit platforms.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should link your application with [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z%28VS.80%29.aspx) to make more than 2GB available to the application. Then you can use up to 4GB on a 64-bit OS in a 32-bit application.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit apps have a virtual address space allowing up to 4GB to be addressed on a 64-bit version of windows.

The [4-Gigabyte Tuning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613473(VS.85).aspx) section in the Win32 and COM Development doc on MSDN, explains the **/LARGEADDRESSAWARE** linker switch. Switching it on will allow 32-bit apps to address up to 4GB of memory.

See the [Memory Management section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366779(VS.85).aspx) in the MSDN Library. Use of the WIN32 memory management services functions provides functionality that is not available in the C run-time library.  Whether or not you need this functionality is up to you.